# "to be" or "be" that is my question

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

Does this grammar structure fit here?

1. Nanotechnology is to develop further, as its positive aspects cannot be denied, but **be** treated with extreme caution.
2. Nanotechnology is to develop further, as its positive aspects cannot be denied, but **to be** treated with extreme caution.

Which one is correct? Maybe this construction doesn't fit here and I should stick to "we must treat it..."?

Comment: You need to repeat "is" or use some other modal: "... but is to be treated / but needs to be treated / but should be treated ..."

Comment: _To be_ or not _to be_, that is the question... (I never thought Shakespeare would ever pop into my mind again)

Comment: Since it's simply the elision of words as part of a parallel structure, either is fine. Which words sound more natural to remove (if any) is another question, and one that's subjective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The start of the sentence "Nanotechnology is to develop further..." doesn't make sense to me. If it's a prediction, you should use "will develop/be developed further..."

If you mean it as a recommendation, you would at least have to use a passive structure, "Nanotechnology is to be developed further", because you can't recommend to nanotechnology what it ought to do.

You'd be safer using "Nanotechnology should be developed further...", with a parallel structure in the last clause "...but it should be treated with extreme caution."